# Real time server status on another linux server

Tags: monitoring, performance-monitoring

I'm looking to make some sort of readable file(pipe?) on my two web servers that shows the id of the mysql server with the least load to use in load balancing as well as some other applications. I'm also wanting it to be in real-time, not just something frequently updated via cron job.

Where should I start?

Comment: You can use a function to return the system load and use it. for example PHP have `sys_getloadavg` which you can use.

Comment: Since I'm running on a LAMP stack this should work perfectly! I didn't realize php had the ability to check the system load.

Answer (score 1):

Writing your own server attribute discovery system will be more work to maintain than you realize. Consider using an orchestration tool like Mcollective with Facter to perform this task.

e.g., Install Facter and Mcollective, and setup a central queue. Make sure you can do "mco ping" and see all of your servers.

Then, to discover facts from the servers, you can do:

```
mco facts --json uptime
```

Which returns the current uptime (fact) from all of my servers. You can write a custom fact to discover anything you need on your servers, such as number of current mysql connections, cpu load, etc...

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it -- you could have a cron job execute 'top' - which should work, and send it to a text file (or html file in a web server directory)

command:

```
top -n 1 -b | head -n 10 > index.html
```

run n=1 iteration of top, head gives n=10 lines (you don't have to have the head command, i just like the control)

be sure to use exact paths for the commands so that the cron job works properly

-

sample results:

cat index.html

top - 15:24:49 up 121 days,  6:13,  1 user,  load average: 0.03, 0.18, 0.21
Tasks:  62 total,   1 running,  61 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
Cpu(s):  0.2%us,  0.0%sy,  0.0%ni, 99.8%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Mem:   8388608k total,  6909524k used,  1479084k free,        0k buffers
Swap:  2097152k total,    95012k used,  2002140k free,  6143764k cached

PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND
    1 root      20   0 19232  196   88 S  0.0  0.0   0:02.17 init
    2 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kthreadd/109402
    3 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 khelper/109402

Comment: If you want only network data, you could install iftop which shows ip addresses or domain names of connections